# How to change all the folder files permission private into public in Digital Ocean spaces?

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I have synced my AWS s3:bucket to digital ocean spaces. In my s3:bucket, my all folders/files permission is in Private- but anyone will read. After, the sync s3 - spaces, my all folders/files permission is in Private. Because of that anyone not able to read.

So I want to make my all folders/files permission is in Public. Is there a way to change through the control panel of the Digitalocean. But I have lots of data. If anyone has an idea about it?

Please help me out from this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which tool are you using to sync, rclone?

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe - yeah.. I am using rclone.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

before move/copy file you have to set acl to public in rclone config (rclone.conf) file like this

```
[spaces]
acl = public-read
```

if your files are already in **Digital Ocean spaces** there is no way to modify permission with rclone, you have to use **s3cmd**, the setup is very slimier to rclone. After setup success, use these command to change permission.

#### Make a file public

```
s3cmd setacl s3://spacename/file.txt --acl-public
```

#### Make all the files inside a path public

```
s3cmd setacl s3://spacename/path/to/files/ --acl-public --recursive
```

> learn how to setup s3cmd for space
> https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3cmd/
>
> usage https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3cmd-usage/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Suppose I will make acl = public before start sync. It will work for all files/folders which I have already in AWS with private permission?

Comment: Yeah. My files are already in "Digital Ocean Spaces". So, I used s3cmd to change the permission private to public. The changing permission process is going on.

Comment: Thanks Kyaw Kyaw Soe. I will try this for next sync.